# SSRS Web Service proxy not showing parameters for Render class

Tags: java, wsdl, ssrs-2008

I am trying to use a web service to connect to SSRS from a SAP Portal environment. I have created the proxy classes from ReportService2005.asmx and can see that there is a Render class in the list. The issue is it does not have any of the parameters described in the other examples I have seen. It looks like this:

render(Render arg0)

What am I missing? I was able to retreive the report parameters fine with getReportParameters from ReportingService2005.asmx as it had the proper parameters.

Code:

```
      InitialContext itc = new InitialContext();
      Render r = new Render(); // just to fill in the 

      ReportExecutionService exec = (ReportExecutionService)itc.lookup("java:comp/env/SSRS_WS_Proxy_ReportExecution2005");

      ReportExecutionServiceSoap exec_port = (ReportExecutionServiceSoap)exec.getLogicalPort("ReportExecutionServiceSoap", ReportExecutionService.class);

      exec_port.render(r); //obviously not going to work without the correct parameters 
                           // and r is just to show the type of parameter it takes
```